# Draw KmlLayer data as polygons and not polylines on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, kml, layer

I've converted an .shp file, downloaded from Zillow http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm, to .kml using the "Quantum GIS Desktop", when I loaded it on the map I found that I can't click inside of the boundary to get the name of the county since Google has drawn the boundaries using polylines, I can only click on the line which is very unusable. You can see what I mean on this page: http://webappscustoms.com/tests/google_maps/Zillow/map/index.html.

So I was wondering if there was an easy way to tell the Google Maps API to draw polygons instead of polylines? Perhaps there's a way, while converting .shp to .kml file in the Quantum, to tell the boundaries to be polygons and not polylines? ..If I open the converted file in Google Earth I can click inside of the region and get the default data without any problems.

And if there's no any easy options, then probably I could draw the polygons manually but I'm not sure how to extract the latitude/longitude from a .kml file using Google Maps API and if it's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your KML, they are Polygons.  You have them styled the way they are being displayed:

```
<Style>
 <LineStyle>
  <color>ff0000ff</color>
 </LineStyle>
 <PolyStyle>
  <fill>0</fill>
 </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

I think you want

```
<fill>1</fill>
```

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/il_neighbourhoods_fill1_kml.xml)

Comment: That was even simpler than I anticipated. It worked! Thank you for your response and all the best!